# Mysqldump fails on dumping virtual column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a largish (4GB) database, that I would like to dump, but when using the mysqldump tool (the MariaDB version, `Ver 10.19 Distrib 10.4.21-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)`), my dumping process has always failed at the same table, with the not so helpful error message:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW CREATE TABLE `AffiliateProgramsCampaigns`': Lost connection to MySQL server during query (2013)
```

I've tried to debug this error, but none of the obvious solutions worked for me, so I did a little experimenting, and found the culprit of my problem. The table in question, contains a `VIRTUAL` column, which strangely, if I remove, the dump finishes succesfully. I've digged a little more, but found no such error anywhere else relating to dumping MariaDB databases with virtual columns. Adding the `--verbose` option to the dump, is not helping either, as it gives me no other significant information.

As the query fails at the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` part, I've figured it has something to do with the structure of the CREATE TABLE query, but when I only try to dump the structure of this database, everything works like a charm. So I am stuck at the moment, trying to solve this issue. I could give up on the virtual column in this specific table, but if there would be any alternative, even a different dump tool, I would more likely go with that solution. Any advice, on how to fix this, or at least how to debug the problem more throughly would be appreciated!

Here are some other debug informations, that could be helpful:

This is the end of the `--verbose` dump output:

```
-- Retrieving view structure for table ActionLogReferences...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table ActionLogs...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table AffiliatePrograms...
-- It's base table, skipped
-- Retrieving view structure for table AffiliateProgramsCampaigns...
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW CREATE TABLE `AffiliateProgramsCampaigns`': Lost connection to MySQL server during query (2013)
```

And here is the CREATE TABLE syntax for the table in question:

```
CREATE TABLE `AffiliateProgramsCampaigns` (
 `AffiliateProgramsCampaignId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Description` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `StartDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `EndDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `IsActivated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'This column shows if this campaign was manually activated.',
 `Status` tinyint(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if(`IsActivated`,if(curdate() between `StartDate` and `EndDate`,1,0),0)) VIRTUAL COMMENT 'The final, computed status of the campaign. When querying, you should use this to check the status.',
 `affiliatePrograms_AffiliateProgramId` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `images_ImageId_BaseImage` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The id of the base image.',
 `images_ImageId_CoverImage` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The id of the cover image.',
 PRIMARY KEY (`AffiliateProgramsCampaignId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The query that is reported by `mysqldump` btw runs every single time I try it, both from `phpymadmin` and from the command line `mysql` interface. I also tried dumping with different users, even with the `root` user, but I always get the same error, at the same spot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the `CURDATE()` function that was used in the virtual column. By changing the function, to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, the issue is solved.

Also posted a bug report on the official boards: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26619